# Indexing from Drupal Search API to Solr: Bad Request

Tags: drupal, solr, drupal-7

I run Drupal 7, MySQL and Solar 4.10.2
Solr itself works fine (if I index the examples), the connection from Drupal to Solr itself is ok. I don't get a warning about the incompatible schema.xml (because I copied it over)

The error in drupal is the following:

```
SearchApiException while indexing: "400" Status: Bad Request: Bad Request{"responseHeader":{"status":400,"QTime":110},"error":{"msg":"Bad Request\n\n\n\nrequest: http://192.168.0.232:7574/solr/collection1/update?update.distrib=TOLEADER&distrib.from=http%3A%2F%2F192.168.0.232%3A8983%2Fsolr%2Fcollection1%2F&wt=javabin&version=2","code":400}} in SearchApiSolrConnection->checkResponse() (line 536 of REDACTED\modules\search_api_solr\includes\solr_connection.inc).
```

The error in Solr:

```
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Bad Request



request: http://192.168.0.232:7574/solr/collection1/update?update.distrib=TOLEADER&distrib.from=http%3A%2F%2F192.168.0.232%3A8983%2Fsolr%2Fcollection1%2F&wt=javabin&version=2
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.ConcurrentUpdateSolrServer$Runner.run(ConcurrentUpdateSolrServer.java:241)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

There are similar errors here on stack, but either it's "I forgot the schema" or "I reinstalled the modules", which both didn't help.

I fail to find out how to debug it properly. My Solr experience is limited (this is all my Solr experience).

Anyone got any idea? Need more info to help me or can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Seems like it might be an issue with SolrCloud where it's unable to contact the current leader - the bad request is generated internally in Solr (as I'd think the Drupal code would reference PHP and not solrj). Do you run in SolrCloud mode, and have you check the current state of the cluster?

Comment: @MatsLindh OK, that pointed me in the right direction. The cluster was indeed the cause. If I don't run it in cloud, it works fine. Stuff is indexed. I'll see if I can figure out why it's acting weird when in cloud mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself... somewhat.

The problem is that the schema.xml of the module isn't working properly with 4.10.x for some weird reason. It works if you DON'T start Solr in Cloud mode. It works properly with 3.x even in Cloud mode.

I know, this isn't really helping but maybe you have the same problem as me.